# Vuejs - Vue app render method with dynamic template (compiled) is throwing some error

Tags: dynamic, vue.js, vue-component

I am trying to build a vuejs dashboard whose template is loaded from ajax request.

A sample structure of my dashboard template is

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <number-widget :option="option1"></number-widget>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried following code but it's throwing

> TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

```
        var vDashboard = new Vue({
            el: '#vue-dashboard',
            components:{ ... }
            data: {
                template: dashboardTemplate,
                _compile: null,
                option1: { ... }
            },
            render: function (h, b, v) {
                this._compile = Vue.compile(this.template).render;
                return this._compile();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `return h(this._compile)`

Comment: nope.. that gives me `ReferenceError: _m is not defined` error

Comment: Ah you're absolutely right, as it should.

Comment: thnx @Ohgodwhy for the hint, got the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, found out the issue. I was using `Vue.compile().render` it should be just `Vue.compile()`..

```
render: function (h, b, v) {
    var compile = Vue.compile(this.template);
    return h(compile);
}
```